# spark multithreading shared dataframe

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have tried loading in a thread a dataframe from an avro file. It doesn't seem to error out, but I am unable to access that dataframe in other threads. My understanding is all threads will have the same spark context.

Have anyone accomplished this?

I tried:

```
val thread = new Thread {
     override def run {
     var a = 1
     while (a > 0) {
       val someDF = Seq(
                    (8, "bat"),
                    (64, "mouse"),
                    (-27, "horse")
                  ).toDF("number", "word")
    } }

   }
thread.start


someDF.show
```

Comment: You create a local object, which is out of scope outside `run`.  What do  you expect here? Being able to access `someDF` in outer scope?

Comment: yes I want to access that dataframe.

Comment: In Java, but the point is exactly the same [accessing shared variable from inside a Runnable class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7147636/9613318)

Comment: I guessed that, thank you.  I'll see if you can make a temp view from inside a thread.